# NPE when testing servlet with testNG and Mockito

Tags: java, servlets

everyone! I have a problem with tests servlets
I REFRESHED MY TEST, NPE at this line in Servlet 
"session.setAttribute("login", user.getLogin());"

My servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

private IUserDao dao;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    dao = (IUserDao) getServletContext().getAttribute("Users");
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (dao.isUserExists(request.getParameter(LOGIN), request.getParameter(PASSWORD))) {
        User user = dao.getUser(request.getParameter(LOGIN));

        session.setAttribute("login", user.getLogin());
        session.setAttribute("message", "you logged in successfully!");
        response.sendRedirect("hello.jsp");
        return;
    }

    User notUser = new User(request.getParameter(LOGIN), request.getParameter(PASSWORD));
    session.setAttribute("user", notUser);
    session.setAttribute("wrongUserCredentials", "Wrong login or password");
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

}
```

}

`

My test:

```
@Test(groups = "positive")
public class TestLoginServlet extends Mockito {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getRootLogger();
@Mock
private IUserDao dao;




@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}

@Test
public void testDoPostLoginServlet() throws Exception {

            HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    HttpSession session = mock(HttpSession.class);
    ServletConfig config = mock(ServletConfig.class);
    ServletContext context = mock(ServletContext.class);

    UserDaoInMemory daoInMemory = new UserDaoInMemory();
    UserDaoInMemory spy = spy(daoInMemory);
    User user = new User("kote", "Qw12");

    when(config.getServletContext()).thenReturn(context);
    when(request.getParameter(LOGIN)).thenReturn(user.getLogin());
    when(request.getParameter(PASSWORD)).thenReturn(user.getPassword());
    when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
    when(request.getServletContext()).thenReturn(context);
    when(context.getAttribute("Users")).thenReturn(spy);
    doReturn(true).when(spy).isUserExists(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword());

    LoginServlet servlet = new LoginServlet();
    servlet.init(config);
    servlet.doPost(request, response);

    verify(request, atLeast(1)).getParameter(LOGIN);
    verify(request, atLeast(1)).getParameter(PASSWORD);
    LOGGER.info("Passed");
}
```

}

Output:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.epam.denys_leunov.java.lesson9.servlets.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:32)
    at com.epam.denys_leunov.java.lesson9.servlets.TestLoginServlet.testDoPostLoginServlet(TestLoginServlet.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:74)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
    enter code here
    enter code here

Comment: I have a problem at this line if (dao.isUserExists(request.getParameter(LOGIN), request.getParameter(PASSWORD))), why it isn't mock by this doReturn(true).when(spy).isUserExists("kote","Qw12");

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `IUserDao dao;`, which is initialized in method `public void init()`.
So, to get rid of NullPointerException you have to call `init()` before executing `doPost`

Updated:
Try to add in test before `servlet.doPost(request, response);`

```
ServletContext sc = servlet.getServletContext();
ServletContext scSpy = spy(sc);
// return dao from servlet context 
doReturn(spy).when(scSpy).getAttribute("Users");
servlet.init();
```

Comment: Thank's for answer, but i have new NPE
at servlets.LoginServlet.init(LoginServlet.java:23)

Comment: i did it, but have new NPE at this line    servlets.LoginServlet.init(LoginServlet.java:23) 
    dao = (IUserDao) getServletContext().getAttribute("Users");

Comment: I updated answer, maybe that help you

Comment: thank's, but NPE at  ServletContext sc = servlet.getServletContext(); What could be the reason?

Comment: You have to put my code after your line: `LoginServlet servlet = new LoginServlet();`

Comment: of course, i did it!